# Django view dramatically slower when called via HTTP request than when called via Django shell

Tags: django

I have a view that retrieves a class instance and runs a method on it:

```
def run_loader(request, loader_id):
    try:
        pl = Loader.objects.get(pk=loader_id)
        pl.run()
        return JsonResponse({ 'success': True}, safe=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return JsonResponse(
            'error', safe=False
        )
```

When this view is run via an HTTP request to the associated path, processing is approximately 300 times slower than when run via the Django shell using `RequestFactory`.

I have tried hitting the path using both Axios and Postman, with the same result.

The method, `run()`, involves processing many rows of Pandas dataframes. When the view is run via the Django shell, it takes a few minutes to complete.

Eventually I'll move this to an asynchronous task worker, but I'm baffled by the speed disparity. What could be the cause?

Comment: "when the view is run via the shell, it takes a few minutes to complete" you are saying that when the view is called via http this takes a few minutes * 300, i.e. hours?

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes